# How to CONCAT two columns into an email address

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a university table that consists of prospective student information.  I need to populate the email address column and the format is first_name.last_name@su.edu.

I have been trying to used the CONCAT method but every time I execute the code I run into an error stating that 'invalid number of arguements'.

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, '.', last_name, '@su.edu') AS prospect_email FROM prospect;
```

The expected output should be first_name.last_name@su.edu.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Oracle SQL developer

Comment: SQL developer is not a database it is an IDE. While typically used with Oracle DB it can be 'used' with other DBMS, example Postgres, and DB2.

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT accepts two params, CONCAT returns first_name concatenated with '.'.

You could nest bunch of concats like

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, CONCAT('.', CONCAT(last_name, '@su.edu'))) AS prospect_email FROM prospect;
```

but it's easier to use concatenation operator ||:

```
SELECT first_name || '.'  || last_name || '@su.edu' AS prospect_email FROM prospect;
```

See the [concat](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) and [concatenation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm#i997789) documentation.